# Prediction of the next number 0 to 9 that doesn't have a particular sequence

Tags: statistics, prediction

How to predict a number from *0 to 9* that are random and doesn't have any particular sequence that the numbers are following?

Comment: Just generate a random number between 0 and 9; this approach has 10% accuracy, though  . In all seriousness, if the underlying process is purely random and each generated number is drawn equiprobably and independently from the rest, no predictive model can have an accuracy that is significantly greater than 10%.

Comment: @noe I would change the phrasing to say that accuracy cannot reliably be better than $10\%$ (unless we know one of the digits to appear particularly frequently), but I’m $100\%$ on board with the idea that going further is impossible with the digits appearing purely at random. (I would define “purely at random” this way). // [Related](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/622252/247274)